# Favicon Not Showing Up (w/ cloudflare)

Tags: javascript, html, css, host, cloudflare

I am using 000webhost as a Host, then after I uploaded files, the only thing happen is the contents show but not the favicon. I am using CloudFlare too secure my website I've purge everything.

the site is https://ravenshangar.tk/ (Not showing Favicon) 
the 000webhost site is https://ravenshangar.000webhostapp.com/ (Showing Favicon)

[Showing Favicon (000webhost)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tauLf.png)

[Not Showing Favicon (CloudFlare)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFtCj.png)

Comment: Check properly after clear cache. Favicone shown in both links.Try to use CTRL+F5 to refresh page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to include favicon inside head tag :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Thanks @Vatanay Özbeyli!